# Noob to tor/tails/darknet...forgot to disable Javascript. What to do now?

Tags: javascript, tor, darknet

I am a noob as stated in title. I didn't know how to disable Javascript before visiting some not-so-legit sites. So what can I do? I was using tor, I know this is not enough so I have tails ring a persistent volume on a USB stick as added security. Can I go back, with javascript disabled, and create a new user name and information for those sites and be ok? I just browsed these sites but did create user info.

So is browsing sites illegal? The sites were certain markets. Can I somehow erase my history? Literally visited 2 markets (looking no keys were exchanged nor vital information not even a name).

To disable JS, I just change the level of security on tor, correct? If no, please if you have time explain or point me to a site that can.

Comment: Staying "anonymous" on the internet. There's always something that will give you away. Once you've created a history, assume it's permanent. Your computer isn't the only place history is found.

Comment: define "be ok"?

Comment: "Is browsing sites illegal" is up to the country you are browsing from. As it is a legal question, we are not qualified to answer it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The sequence to check-up is just exactly the same as if you were browsing from unsafe place, like public open wifi : full system scan, log checking, anti-malware tools risen to the maximum protection level. Tor/darknet is *just* a network, no darknet-specific problems there so far : you can leak your data with the same result as in clearnet/internet.

Answer (score 4):

Tor should have noscript installed. You simply click on the NoScript extension and click disable javascript on all sites.

Unfortunately, once you've done something on the internet you can't change it. You can't go back and do it again differently, just like you can't in real life.

Consider refraining from doing things you might later regret, especially if you don't really understand what you're doing.

Comment: "Tor Browser" comes with NoScript, there's a difference.